# How quickly does a Pokémon lose motivation?

Tags: pokemon-go

With the new gym update, Pokémon have a motivation meter while defending a gym. This meter degrades over time, which makes it easier to remove that Pokémon from its defending position. Motivation can be reduced quicker when it loses a fight defending the gym, but can also be replenished using berries. However, if a Pokémon is left alone at a gym too long, it will lose all motivation and be returned to you as soon as it is defeated a single time.

How quickly does this motivation meter degrade on its own? That is, how long will a Pokémon defend a gym naturally?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this article](http://heavy.com/games/2017/06/pokemon-go-how-quickly-do-pokemon-lose-motivation-loss-formula/), which references [this reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/6j0l6p/motiviation_cp_loss_over_the_time_analyzed/?st=j49urawf&sh=198c4570) post, and it is calculated that Pokémon lose motivation over time at:

1. ~10% MPH for Pokémon with CP >= 3000
2. ~1% MPH for Pokémon with CP < 3000

> It would appear that Pokemon with over 3000 CP lose roughly 10 percent motivation every hour, while Pokemon with CP below 3000 lose about one percent motivation every hour, [one gamer observer on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/6j0l6p/motiviation_cp_loss_over_the_time_analyzed/?st=j49urawf&sh=198c4570).
>
> While CP and motivation are not the same thing, they are connected, as losing motivation decreases a Pokemon’s CP. Just to throw out some examples of how motivation can affect CP, one Reddit user found that a 3348CP Tyranitar and a 3094CP Gyarados both lost 3CP roughly every 30 seconds; a 2800CP Blissey, a 2795CP Donphan, and a 2753CP Alakazam all lost 3CP in four minutes; and a 2409CP Dragonite lost 3CP in 4 minutes and 20 seconds.

When the Pokémon is defeated, it is calculated the motivation will drop an additional ~20%

> In battle, Pokemon generally lose about 20 percent motivation every time they are defeated, meaning defeating a Pokemon five times in battle should be enough to drain its motivation.

Comment: Any idea if this is based on max CP or current CP? I.e. does the motivation drop more slowly after the CP gets under 3000?

Comment: @Kat I think I read somewhere that it is based on max CP, but I'll need to confirm that.