# Do IVs affect a Pokémon's motivation degradation in a gym?

Tags: pokemon-go

Say I have two Pokémon (let's just say Vaporeon) in a gym and they both have the exact same CP.

**Vaporeon 1** has an IV score of 100%, which means that Attack, Defense, and Health have a perfect 15/15 score.

**Vaporeon 2** has an IV score of 10% (or less), so basically, it has the worst stats when it comes to Attack, Defense and Health.

Will their motivation deplete at the same rate, when placed in a Gym?

Will Vaporeon 1's motivation deplete slower or will they both degrade at the same rate?

Comment: I answered a [related](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/311666/how-quickly-does-a-pok%C3%A9mon-lose-motivation/311758#311758) question, and right now it appears it's primarily CP based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that appears to affect CP decay is the original CP of the pokemon.

If its CP >= 3000, it will lose 10% of its original CP per hour.
If its CP < 3000, it will lose ~1% of its original CP per hour.

Numbers from [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/6j0ijr/lets_do_some_maths/djapz3j/)

Answer (score -2):

When defending a gym, the Pokemon will lose approximately 25% of its CP regardless of how much.

- 3000 Dragonite will lose ~750
- 2200 Gyarados will lose ~550
- 1200 Espeon will lose ~300

It takes 4 wins to beat a gym 100% as long as nobody is feeding berries and after the 2nd win you will see all the Pokemon are at 50% their original CP.